# How to find a smarty variable where was called in prestashop 1.6

Tags: php, smarty, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I am learning prestashop, for example I want modify the delivery PDF format. In the **delivery-slip.tpl** file:

```
 <td colspan="12">

   {$product_tab}

 </td>
```

How can I located where the {$product_tab} was injected? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey {$product_tab} this variable is coming from controller of delivery-slip which is likely "deliverySlipController.php" in controllers folder.

Answer (score 1):

This is not the exact answer to the question but it helps you to find the proper controller you are looking for,

first you need to find the whole project , then you will get different controllers also .tpl files as your search result.

you just going through the controllers you can easily find it out a line like

```
$this->setTemplate('delivery-slip.tpl ');
```

this will help u to find it out..

Answer (score 0):

All the "includes" in the `delivery-slip.tpl` (and other pdf related templates) can be found as sub-templates of the main template. So for `{$product_tab}` the template is `delivery-slip.product-tab.tpl`

**edit** the other answers give the right approach for the way you would go about finding where variables are defined. For your specific case though, the smarty variable is actually more like an "include".